# How to compare two objects of same class nd check if they are equal? What is the Difference b/w objects and references

Tags: java, object

I find it difficult to understand the result of following code.

```
File x = new File("myFile.txt");
File y = new File("myFile.txt");
System.out.println(x==y); //outputs false
```

I dont understand why this outputs false. Please help

Comment: Not sure if your question is about the meaning of object references or the usage of `==` and `equals`.

Comment: What do you think should happen and why do you think so?

Comment: I know that two references are equal if they point to same object. but x and y appears to point to same object?

Comment: No they don't. They point to two different File objects. These objects might reference the same physical files, but they are unique objects.

Comment: Each time you call `new ...` you are creating new (separate) instance. Two separate instances can have same state (like two people can have same name) but it doesn't mean they are the same (same != equal). So `==` checks if two references are pointing to *same* object, if you want to check if two objects are equal use `obj1.equals(obj2)`.